# How do i populate this variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run something like this from a bash script:

```
HOST=foo
DIR=bar

ssh user@$HOST "
function test
{
    CURHOST=$HOST
    cd $DIR
    mkdir -p $CURHOST
}; test"
```

When I run it with `set -x` I see that it translates to this:

```
+ ssh user@foo '
   function test
   {
       CURHOST=foo
       cd bar
       mkdir -p
   }; test
```

and then of course it complains about `mkdir -p` having no argument. Why is this and how can I set a local variable in there?

Comment: I recommend to use a here document instead of the multiline string, that is `ssh user@$HOST <<EOF\nfunction test\n...\nEOF`.

Comment: Also you can use `local` for variables local to a function. And finally, even though you can declare a function using `function test` it is more common to use `test()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent substitution, you can use either single-quotes `'...'` or a backslash `\`; for example, this command:

```
echo '$foo' \$foo "\$foo"
```

will print this:

```
$foo $foo $foo
```

and will not use the variable `foo`.

In your case, rather than using `"..."` for the whole argument, you probably should use `'...'` everywhere except where you specifically need substitution. So:

```
HOST=foo
DIR=bar

ssh user@$HOST '
function test
{
    CURHOST='"$HOST"'
    cd $DIR
    mkdir -p $CURHOST
}; test'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the dollar sign:

```
echo "
function test
{
    CURHOST=$HOST
    cd $DIR
    mkdir -p \$CURHOST
}; test"
```

gives you:

```
function test
{
    CURHOST=foo
    cd bar
    mkdir -p $CURHOST
}; test
```